# Finding supported feature set of USB-C port

Tags: usb, usb-c

As far as I can tell, USB-C is a wonderful port that supports a confusing  amalgamation of different protocols.

I have a Lenovo T480 which supports USB-C charging but it seems to always be a roll of the dice whether a new charger (and cable) will successfully charge, even if it provides an appropriate voltage and amperage.
If new hardware does not successfully charge, it is nearly impossible to tell what the problem is.

**What hardware, software, or techniques can I use to determine what PD/AM/3.1/etc. features are supported by a USB-C port?** (Bonus points if it also can determine the feature set of the cable.)

Prior answers such as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1365874/) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1199917/what-is-the-d-shaped-icon-next-to-my-usb-c-port/1200112#1200112) explain the complex landscape surrounding this port but not how to navigate it. A cursory web search mostly brings up articles complaining about how confusing this all is. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I'd ask Lenovo support what their design permits https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t480-type-20l5-20l6/contactus

Comment: @K7AAY - I provide the laptop as an example, but I seek a general approach for other devices with poor documentation.

Comment: the best of Irish luck to yaz.